# Meu codigo está tendo loop infinito, o que está errado

Tags: php, javascript, html

Meu codigo está apresentando um loop infinito, o que pode está errado

**Codigo em javascript**

```
// Mensagens
var fromm = null, startt = 0;urll = "chat/novo.php";
$(document).ready(function(){
    //from = prompt("Daniel Usuario aqui");
    loadd();
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        $.post(urll, {
            message: $('#mensagem').val(),
            from: <?=$id?>
        });
        $('#mensagem').val('');
        return false;
    })
});

function loadd(){
    $.get(urll + '?startt=' + startt, function(resultt){
        if(resultt.itemss){
            resultt.itemss.forEach(itemm =>{
                startt = itemm.id_chat;
                $('#cli').append(renderCliente(itemm));
            });
            //$('#cli').animate({scrollTop: $('#cli')[0].scrollHeight});

        };
        loadd();
    });
}

function renderCliente(itemm){

    var nomee
    var cliente
    var dep
    nomee = itemm.nome_chatid
    cliente = itemm.nome_cliente
    dep = itemm.nome_sis


    return '<div class="msg"><p>'+itemm.id_chatid+nomee+'</p>'+cliente+'<span>'+dep+'</span></div>';
}
// Fim Mensagens
```

**codigo em html**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="cli" id="cli"></div>
```

**codigo em php**

```
$db = new mysqli("$host","$user","$pass","$db");
if($db->connect_error){
    die ("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
}
$resultt = array();
//print menssages
$startt = isset($_GET['startt']) ? intval($_GET['startt']):0;
$itemss = $db->query("SELECT * FROM chat_ID CID LEFT JOIN colaborador CO ON CID.atendente_chatid=CO.id_pessoa LEFT JOIN cliente CL ON CID.cliente_chatid=CL.id_cliente LEFT JOIN sistemas SIS ON SIS.id_sis=CID.departamento_chatid WHERE CID.status_chatid='N' AND CID.id_chatid > ". $startt);
while($row = $itemss->fetch_assoc()){
    $resultt['itemss'][] = $row;
}


$db->close();


header('Acess-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode($resultt);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando a página é carregada, você acaba chamando a função:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

E dentro da mesma, você faz a chamada da função `loadd`, até aí sem problemas.

Acontece que sua função `loadd` é recursiva e enquanto a condição `$.get(urll + '?startt=' + startt, function(resultt){` for verdadeira, a `loadd` vai chamar ela mesma... Gerando o seu loop infinito.

---

Uma opção é remover essa recursão da função `loadd`:

```
function loadd(){
    $.get(urll + '?startt=' + startt, function(resultt){
        if(resultt.itemss){
            resultt.itemss.forEach(itemm =>{
                startt = itemm.id_chat;
                $('#cli').append(renderCliente(itemm));
            });
            //$('#cli').animate({scrollTop: $('#cli')[0].scrollHeight});

        };
    });
}
```

---

Caso você precise manter esse `loadd` de forma recursiva, você pode tentar manter apenas o maior `itemm.id_chat` na variável `startt` e só invocar a recursão caso o `startt` seja maior que o seu valor anterior e a API retornou dados:

```
function loadd(){
    $.get(urll + '?startt=' + startt, function(resultt){
        if(resultt.itemss){

            //Manter o valor anterior armazenado
            let oldStartt = startt;

            resultt.itemss.forEach(itemm =>{

                //Só pegar o valor de id_chat caso seja superior
                if(itemm.id_chat > startt) {
                    startt = itemm.id_chat;
                }

                $('#cli').append(renderCliente(itemm));
            });
            //$('#cli').animate({scrollTop: $('#cli')[0].scrollHeight});

            //Só invoca a loadd caso o id anterior seja menor que o retornado
            if(startt > oldStartt) {
                loadd();
            }
        };
    });
}
```

Acredito que isso não seja necessário, é mais para exemplificar a saída da recursão, com certeza será chamada mais de uma vez, levando em consideração que a variável `startt` começa em zero.